# Not sure why inspecting element on windows is different that what im seeing on mobile?

Tags: css, html

I just started learning Html/CSS two months ago and im having a really hard time trying to make my projects responsive. When im viewing the project on my mobile phone it looks how i want it to look, but when I inspect in window some elements aren't lining up correctly vice versa.

If anyone can help that'll be great.

Comment: I heard its a little easier to start with the mobile version of a website so thats what im doing, im having such a hard time with media queries